# Use custom JRE for Wildfly 10

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

Can I choose a custom JRE for a Wildfly Application Server with a property like `standalone.bat -Djava.jre=<path>`

For my project, it is important that I can't change the value of parameter JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set the `JAVA_HOME` used by WildFly.

For Linux/UNIX, check the `standalone.conf` file:

```bash
# Specify the location of the Java home directory.  If set then $JAVA will
# be defined to $JAVA_HOME/bin/java, else $JAVA will be "java".
#
#JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jdk"
```

For Windows, check the `standalone.conf.bat` file:

```vb
rem #
rem # Specify the location of the Java home directory (it is recommended that
rem # this always be set). If set, then "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" will be used as
rem # the Java VM executable; otherwise, "%JAVA%" will be used (see below).
rem #
rem set "JAVA_HOME=C:\opt\jdk1.6.0_23"
```

Simply uncomment the line that sets the `JAVA_HOME` variable and update its value with the desired path.

Comment: thanks for your comment but there isn't a solution for my problem. I can't use any variable like JAVA_HOME or JAVA

Comment: @root404 This approach will change the `JAVA_HOME` variable used by WildFly. It won't affect the environment variables defined in your system.

Comment: The option "-D...." is something which is evaluated from the already running JVM, so it is started.

Comment: @wfink Good spot!

Comment: Pay attention to the code in the `standalone.conf.bat`

So if you have set the `JAVA_OPTS` the execution goes straight to the end of the file and it does not set your `JAVA_HOME`, there is `goto JAVA_OPTS_SET`

Comment: If you're running in domain, instead of standalone.conf, use domain.conf (or, on Windows, domain.conf.bat)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home bin/standalone.sh
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You might run

```
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/Java bin/standalone.sh
```

Or the Windows variant of it.
This is similar to change the standalone start script. The JAVA_HOME variable will take only effect to the started process. Every other open shell window will see the original JAVA_HOME

Comment: That's exactly what the `standalone.conf` is for ;)